# Dependabot error with Bitbucket server Clients::Bitbucket::NotFound

Tags: bitbucket, dependabot, dependabot-script

I have tried dependabot-script with Azure devops and had no big hurdles (I noticed Dependabot throws error repo not found when the I used user access token rather than system access token in ADO), but now trying with enterprise Bitbucket server I only see this error.

Has anyone experienced this error?

`docker run --rm -v "$(pwd):/home/dependabot/dependabot-script" -w /home/dependabot/dependabot-script -e BITBUCKET_ACCESS_TOKEN=$BITBUCKET_ACCESS_TOKEN -e GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN=$GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN -e PACKAGE_MANAGER=npm_and_yarn -e PROJECT_PATH=projects/project_name/repos/repo_name bundle exec ruby ./generic-update-script.rb`

Error
*/home/dependabot/dependabot-script/vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/dependabot-common-0.142.0/lib/dependabot/clients/bitbucket.rb:170:in `Clients::Bitbucket::NotFound)*

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in:

```
PROJECT_PATH=projects/project_name/repos/repo_name
```

You have to use

```
PROJECT_PATH=project_name/repo_name
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

At the moment what you try to achieve seems not be implemented in dependabot.

I *guess* by the code at [dependabot-core](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/blob/main/common/lib/dependabot/clients/bitbucket.rb) that bitbucket enterprise (by which I mean bitbucket installed in your company and not cloud) is not supported.
Right at the bottom of the file it reads

```
def base_url
   # TODO: Make this configurable when we support enterprise Bitbucket
   "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/"
 end
```

Unfortunately I did not find further hints if this is really true.

The description of [dependabot-script](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-script) implies that you *can* set an api url and hostname via `BITBUCKET_API_URL` and `BITBUCKET_HOSTNAME`. The defaults there (api 2.0 and bitbucket.org show that they default to the bit bucket cloud API which I believe differs from the enterprise API (at least by the version).

I even tried some of the URLs that are assembled in the dependabot code and half of them work alright on the enterprise bitbucket and some don't (for example `../pullrequests` which is used in the code does not work for me because the correct URL would be `../pull-requests` on enterprise bitbucket)

I also checked with wireshark since I also tried to get this working and found that dependabot-script does send requests to `bitbucket.org` but not my enterprise bitbucket even when I set `BITBUCKET_API_URL` and `BITBUCKET_HOSTNAME`.